# R - Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘car’; LoadLibrary failure

Tags: r, r-car

I want to use function *vif* (to testing multicollinearity) from package *car*. Package "car" was successfully unpacked, but after loading the *library(car)*, I get error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘car’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
>    unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/lenovo/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/libs/x64/Rcpp.dll':
>     LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.

I found older solutions to a similar problem: upgrade/reinstall R and package. Nothing worked. It does't work on version 3.4.4 or 3.5.0. 
In version 3.5.0 was another problem, there does not install data.table package (which is part of the package(car))

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘car’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
>    there is no package called ‘data.table’.

Problem with *data.table* is resolved in [data.table package in R 3.5 does not install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49838553/data-table-package-in-r-3-5-does-not-install).

So, is there a solution of problem with package(car) in version 3.4.4, or should I use version 3.5.0? But will be the function *vif* available?

Comment: I think neither `car` nor `data.table` are at the root of your original problem. What happens when you do `install.packages(c("Rcpp","car"))`? It sounds like Rcpp was not installed correctly/successfully last time.

Comment: Great, it works, thank you.