# Error "there is no package called data.table" when loading afex

Tags: r, data.table, loading, papaja

I'm trying to work through the example.Rmd file from https://github.com/crsh/papaja to learn how to create APA scripts in R markdown.

First step is simply loading the libraries:

````
 ```{r message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
library("papaja")
library("dplyr")
library("afex")

load("../tests/testthat/data/mixed_data.rdata")
```
````

but I just get the following error message:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘afex’ in loadNamespace(j
>   <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): there is
>   no package called ‘data.table’

Afex is installed (I removed it and re-installed it just to check), but it won't load. Any ideas?

Comment: Read the error message: "there is no package called ‘data.table’" - install and load that too

Comment: Sorry  - should have said - that also gives me an error message.  Install.packages(data.table) yields Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘GenomicRanges’ is not available
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘data.table’
  These will not be installed

Comment: BTW I'm using R 3.5 - I wonder if this is the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49838553/data-table-package-in-r-3-5-does-not-install

Comment: Note that currently you should load `afex` or more precisely `haven` (which `afex` imports) before `papaja` (see https://github.com/crsh/papaja/issues/199).

Answer (score 0):

Okay it was a problem with R 3.5 (downloaded on 28.04.2018).  I replaced it with 3.4.4. and afex now loads, no problem. I suspect this is still an issue today: [data.table package in R 3.5 does not install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49838553/data-table-package-in-r-3-5-does-not-install)